# Enforcing Java minimum version to run with "java -version:<value>" doesn't work on Windows

Tags: java, windows, version

I want to enforce the minimum version of JVM my application should run on to 1.6 or greater (i.e. 1.6+).  My understanding is that you can do this using the "-version:" command line argument.  I tried it, and it seemed to work fine under Linux but not under Windows.

**LINUX**

I have a JDK version 1.6.0_21 installed on a Linux machine.  The $JAVA_HOME and $PATH environment variables have been set to what they should be.

I ran the following:

```
$ java -version:1.6+ -version
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

$ java -version:1.5+ -version
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)

$ java -version:1.7+ -version
Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.7+"
```

All seemed to be expected.  "version:1.6+" and "version:1.5+" should work because I have a JDK 1.6.0_21 installed, and "version:1.7+" shouldn't because I don't have a JDK 1.7 installed.

**WINDOWS**

I have the same JDK version 1.6.0_21 installed on a Windows machine (Windows 7 to be more specific).  The %JAVA_HOME% and %PATH% environment variables have been set to what they should be.

I ran the following:

```
$ java -version:1.6+ -version
Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.6+"

$ java -version:1.5+ -version
Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.5+"

$ java -version:1.7+ -version
Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.7+"
```

I got an error for each execution.

- Can anyone explain why does the same command line argument work on Linux, but not on Windows?  Is this a feature or a bug?
- What can I do to fix/work around it?  As much as possible I want to have the same command line arguments applied on both Linux and Windows, so I don't have to specify a different "-version:" argument for Linux and another different one for Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a known bug, at least in the Sun implementation. What is your output (under Windows) of just "java -version"?

Comment: Seem fine to me. Win7.

`C:\>java -version:1.6+ -version
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)`

Comment: @jkraybill "java -version" outputs:

java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode).

Comment: @user802421 That is very strange.  Could you please check if you have both JDK and JRE installed separately?  In my case, I only have a JDK installed, which includes a JRE inside it.  Alos, what environment variables have you set related to Java?

Comment: I have both JDK and JRE, but I'm using the one inside JDK. 
%JAVA_HOME%=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25 %PATH% contains %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: Worksforme!  I've added %java_home%/bin to my path, and set %java_home% to my jdk.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, no the App doesn't have GUI.  It's a server application.

Comment: That is a pity.  JWS (for launching desk-top rich clients) is great for JRE version control.

Answer (score 5):

> - Can anyone explain why does the same command line argument work on Linux, but not on Windows? Is this a feature or a bug?

I don't think it is related to Linux vs. Windows, rather an issue with particular distributions - I can run this just fine on Windows with the Oracle JDK now, i.e. the successor of the Sun JDK (both via PowerShell or CMD):

```
PS> java -version:1.7+ -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

On the contrary, it fails for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with OpenJDK:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
$ java -version:1.7+ -version
Error: Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.7+"
```

A short search reveals the following somewhat inconclusive issues:

- [java -version:release option does not work as documented (JDK-8011079)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8011079)

  - The referenced link is broken, the current one is [https://blogs.oracle.com/ksrini/entry/java_launcher_tricks_with_multiple](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksrini/entry); regardless, I currently fail to see how the referenced docs address the issue though.
- [java -version:1.6+ refuses to work (JDK-6558219)](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6558219)

  - This seems to hint on distribution specifics, and indeed there is [Java -version:spec does not work (#1050911)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-7/+bug/1050911) for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I've confirmed this to still be broken with OpenJDK 6/7 on Ubuntu 13.10 and also on Amazon Linux 2013.09.2, so I suggest to experiment with a different OpenJDK distribution or JDK vendor, in case this issue is prevalent - it's definitely an odd issue, esp. given OpenJDK is meanwhile the [official Java SE 7 Reference Implementation](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/moving_to_openjdk_as_the).

Comment: I got it to work with 64-bit Java8 under Windows, but not with the 32-bit Java8 ("in Program Files (x86)"). Seems like a bug?

Comment: Gosh, it makes me sad the '-version' option didn't get widely implemented. On Ubuntu, it fails for me with all versions of Java I can lay my hands on- e.g. '$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -version:1.8+ -jar bfg.jar' gives 'Error: Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.8+"'

Comment: It does not work for me using 64-bit JDK 1.8 on Windows downloaded from Oracle. Why don't they fix this?

Answer (score 4):

How about doing in Java?

```
String java = System.getProperty("java.specification.version");
double version = Double.valueOf(java);
if (version < 1.6) {
    // Exit
}
```