# Can HotSpot JVM Run in Lower Java Version Mode?

Tags: java, jvm-hotspot

I understand that Java is backwards compatible, which means I can run code compiled in Java 7 on Java 8 JVM. However, is it possible if I want to use OpenJDK 7 library while running on a OpenJDK 8 JVM? Does Hotspot JVM provide such options to run in lower Java version mode?

Comment: You do not need to lower your version for this. As you said, you can use older code together with a new Java version (as long as it does not use code that has been deprecated and then removed). So lets say you want to use a library like Guava, but the version made for Java 7. You can use this in your Java 13 code, no issues. But yes, Java can also be run in a compilation mode, to directly compile for older versions.

Comment: Unfortunately I need exactly the same Java libraray running for OpenJDK 8 as in 7. I instrumented the OpenJDK 7 library by specific bytecode indices, and have to move on to Java 8 now. It would greatly save efforts if I can reuse my code before...

Comment: Again, Java is backwards compatible. You can run code compiled in Java 1 with a Java 13, no issues.

Comment: Although the functionality remains, the bytecode of the same methods in Java 8 is different from Java 7 shown by my results. Just to be clear, I want to use exactly the same Java 7 library for OpenJDK 8, because the instrumentation I have for Java 7 library does not work for Java 8 library. When I run with OpenJDK 8, the bootstrap classes are from Java 8, which I want to change to Java 7.

Comment: So why didn't you say all that in your question?

Comment: Seems unlikely that newer versions of Java would go as far as retaining the old bytecode for every library for every prior version, just in the name of backwards compatibility. The exact bytecode is an implementation detail, so any code that relies on that exact bytecode is brittle by design.

Answer (score 1):

According to Oracle's [Java Platform, Standard Edition Tools Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html) for Java 8, you can use `-version:release`

> Specifies the release version to be used for running the application.
>   If the version of the java command called does not meet this
>   specification and an appropriate implementation is found on the
>   system, then the appropriate implementation will be used.

Comment: I tried `java -version:1.7+ -version` for OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 14, and it showed an error Error: Unable to locate JRE meeting specification "1.7.0_201". According to this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/21333306/10929053), the cause of error may be an issue with distributions. It does not work for me.

Comment: @Binhaoo It looks like it's an old bug. If so, it's never going to work, as I expect they're all working on Java14 now :(

Comment: Even my version java11 is telling me `Error: Specifying an alternate JDK/JRE version is no longer supported.`

Comment: From the looks of this description, this will just look for Java 7 and run it if it finds it - it won't run Java 8 with a Java 7 library.

Comment: @kaya3 I understood it as `>java -version:"1.7.0_201" program` where the java version at the target java executable (not the program) is exactly that version. Alternatively one can use `>java -version:"1.7.0_201+" program` to specify a range given the mentioned version as a minimum.

Comment: *"If the version of the java command called does not meet this specification and an appropriate implementation is found on the system, then the appropriate implementation will be used."* That implies that the `java` command will go looking on the system for a different version in order to run that. If the same JRE could do it, it wouldn't need to go looking for a different one.